# how to fill case class with args from command line?

Tags: scala

If I've a case class like below

```
case class CommandArgs(args : Seq[String])
 val argsOne
 val argsTwo
 val argsThree
```

And If I pass `argsOne, argsTwo, argsThree` from command line, how can I set these params values to CommandArgs's instance variables `(mentioned in above class)` ?

Comment: `CommandArgs(Seq(argsOne, argsTwo, argsThree))`?

Comment: @AminMal, and how to set these params  to case class vals ?

Comment: Oh I see, so these `val`s are case class members. First of all, I would not suggest you do that, I mean it's not safe. The `setField` thing is kind of what we do in Java, in Scala it's better to include these fields in the constructor like `case class CommandArgs(argsOne: String, argsTwo: String, ...)` and have some appropriate apply method that can validate the input `Seq[String]`

Comment: @AminMal, why its not safe ? Secondly, can share any example or reference of doing it like you have mentioned ?

Comment: Because you need to be sure of the number of arguments provided in Seq, to be sure that all the values can be set properly, and also, this requires mutation which is not a good practice in Scala. About the example, I’ll provide a link to scastie rn.

Comment: here's some example, basically you can provide any logic inside your static methods in the companion object: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Ef4wOb9SQiCS0YJilN6vOg

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
case class CommandArgs(args : Seq[String]) {
  val argsOne = args.lift(0).getOrElse(argOneDefault)
  val argsTwo = args.lift(1).getOrElse(argTwoDefault)
  val argsThree = args.lift(2).getOrElse(argThreeDefault)
}
```

But there is a better way that doesn't retain the original `args` in the resulting `case class`:

```
case class CommandArgs(arg1: String, arg2: String, arg3: String)

object CommandArgs {
  def apply(args : Seq[String]): CommandArgs =
    CommandArgs(
      args.lift(0).getOrElse(argOneDefault)
      args.lift(1).getOrElse(argTwoDefault)
      args.lift(2).getOrElse(argThreeDefault)
    )
}
```